# Firefox is not allowing me to connect

Tags: firefox, ip, ip-address, firefox-developer-tools, linode

I created a linode server and I'm trying to access the server through the IP address provided then I opened a new tab in Firefox and typed in https://x.x.x.x and then instead of showing
"connection not secured" - " go back (recommended)"- "Advanced"

"""Unable to connect

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your device’s data or Wi-Fi connection."""
```

Though it shows the "advanced" page but immediately it reverts to "Unable to connect"

So I don't know it it's a proxy problem or a browser problem.